# Dartium not sending httpOnly cookies on websocket handshake

Tags: cookies, websocket, dart, chromium, httponly

I'm using Dartium "Version 34.0.1847.0 aura (264987)" and creating a websocket from Dart. However, my secure session cookie only gets sent on the initial websocket handshake if it is *not* httpOnly. The websocket spec says that httpOnly cookies should be sent, though.

Am I misinterpreting something? Is this a Chromium bug? Is there a  workaround?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [bug in the Chromium issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35660) that seems to describe this behaviour and a change to support it; though it's marked as Fixed in March 2010.

I don't know whether this fix should've made it to Dartium by the time you tried this; or whether Dartium may need its own fix-up for this; but if it's still not working, I would [raise a case](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry) in the Dart issue tracker for investigation.